# Can I use Coinbase-api in an online course

Tags: coinbase-api

I'm creating a paid online course on AI trading and will create a trading application. Can I demonstrate and distribute code that uses Coinbase API in such an application? The students will use their own API keys and their own deployments to connect to Coinbase servers.